# Can Chocolatey exit with the install/script's exit status?

Tags: chocolatey

The command, `choco install`, doesn't seem to throw exceptions. It returns just an array of text, which isn't the most useful thing. I want to install a list of apps and check for/handle failures. I could parse the log, but it would be nice to handle exceptions as they happen.

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
$chocoMsg = (choco install $myApp -y) -join('')

if($chocoMsg -match "install of $myApp was successful.") {
    Write-Host -fo:green 'Success'
} else { 
    # handle errors
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What you are seeing with it not throwing exceptions is interesting behavior, but not what we'd expect. Sounds like a bug. Can you share the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most recent release of Chocolatey, 0.9.10, the ability for Chocolatey to exit with the same exit code as the underlying installer was added.  You can see this issue that describes this functionality here: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/512.  This should allow you to inspect the returned exit code, and then make a decision about how to proceed.

Also two bugs came out of this, both corrected in 0.9.10.3:

- Ignore exit codes for real - https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/827
- Successful exit codes not recognized by choco should return 0 - https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/821

Comment: hmm I tried the following switches, but I don't seem to be getting exit codes (just an array of text)      --usepackagecodes, --usepackageexitcodes, --use-package-codes, --use-package-exit-codes

Comment: Can you confirm what version of Chocolatey you are using?

Comment: Choco version says: v0.9.10.2

Comment: Can you share more about your environment please?

Comment: Windows 10 x64. tried this with a few packages but 7zip for example will not output any error codes with these switches.